# How to have a GridView / AdaptiveGridView with a fixed number of columns/lines?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm developping an electronic inventory soft which replicates the drawers of organizers, so I need to mimic the fact that these organizers have X columns and Y lines of drawers.

Right now, I'm using an AdaptiveGridView (from Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls) and I'm binding the DesiredWidth to a calculated value == the size of the AdaptiveGridView / the number of desired columns.

That works, but there's a caveat : when I'm reaching the minimum size the AdaptiveGridView accepts as DesiredWidth (about 44), the number of columns starts to shrink (to adapt the Windows, which is its purpose, I know :))

I tried to fix the MinWidth of the AdaptiveGridView to 44 * number of columns, and it works, but then, I can't see the columns on the far right => they're starting to be hidden by the right side of the window.

I tried enabling the horizontal scrolling, putting the AdaptiveGridView in a Scrollviewer, … but I can't get the hidden columns to get accessible.

So, do you have an idea to either :

- get a GridView to have a fixed number of columns and rows ?
- get the AdaptiveGridView to let me scroll horizontally when its size is
  larger than the window ?

Thanks all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK guys, I managed to do what I wanted !

How ? Here it is…

First, the XAML part. I encapsulated the AdaptiveGridView in a Grid, and the Grid in a ScrollViewer.
The most important item here is the intermediate Grid. Indeed, I bind its MinWidth property with the minimum size the AdaptiveGridView allow for an element * the number of columns I need, and I also bind its Width to the ViewportWidth property of the Scrollviewer :

```
<ScrollViewer Name="ScrlV" ZoomMode="Enabled" MaxZoomFactor="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" SizeChanged="ScrlV_SizeChanged">
     <Grid MinWidth="{Binding MinGridSize}" Width="{Binding ElementName=ScrlV, Path=ViewportWidth}">
          <control:AdaptiveGridView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="itemsGrid" CanReorderItems="True" CanDragItems="True" ItemsSource="{Binding List}" DesiredWidth="{Binding ReqWidth}" Height="auto" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DrawerItem}" SelectionChanged="itemsGrid_SelectionChanged" AllowDrop="True" DragItemsCompleted="itemsGrid_DragItemsCompleted" />
     </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

So, as a result, when I change the size of the window, I get the event and modify my CurrWidth property accordingly :

```
    private void itemsGrid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Items.CurrWidth = (int)e.NewSize.Width;
    }
```

Then, in the background, the MinGridSize & ReqWidth values are processed (minimum column width set @ 50) :

```
public int CurrWidth
{
    get
    {
        return currwidth;
    }
    set
    {
        currwidth = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrWidth"));
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ReqWidth"));
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MinGridSize"));
    }
}
public int MinGridSize
{
    get
    {
       return 50 * NbrCol;
    }
}
public int ReqWidth
{
   get
   {
      double width = 0;
      if(NbrCol > 0 && CurrWidth > 0)
      {
         width = CurrWidth / NbrCol;
      }
      else
      {
         width = 50;
      }
      return (int)Math.Round(width, 0);
   }
}
```

So, the AdaptiveGridView gets its DesiredWidth property set, and the Grid also got its MinWidth set.

In the end, the Scrollviewer's width is the window one, the inside grid adapts to the Scrollviewer ViewportWidth accordingly, but is restricted to a minimum Width = number of desired columns * minimum size of the column. And the AdaptiveGridView plays its role whenever I change the width of the window, until I hit the minimum width. When it happens, the Grid stops shrinking, the AdaptiveGridView stops adapting, and I can scroll horizontally to see the missing columns.

Cheers !